# javascript validation of textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forms

i want to write a javascript validation cater to using getElementById() and for loop methods that upon submit it will check the textboxes on the page for empty content before posting to the backend codes to handle the information. Any idea?

```
 <html><body>
 <input type="image" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/placebid.png" value="Place Bid" id="iteration_submit" name="iteration_submit" onclick="submitform()">
 </body></html>


<script>
 function submitform(){
            //validation code for textboxes here; if false, do not carry out the submit --> 
        document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: What about jQuery and jQuery validation? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Hi, i have tried a few plugins but they kind of mess up my codes, so i do not really want to use them but just wish to code a simple version that does alert for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say this is your textarea html:

```
<textarea id='mytext' rows=100 cols=100></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
function submitform(){    
    var mytextarea = document.getElementById('mytext');
    if(mytextarea.innerHTML == '')
        alert('nothing'); //will alert nothing
    else
        document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

something like that.

Comment: hi, thanks for your input. what if i have many textareas to check? I need to do a for loop and if an alert is triggered, document must not submit too..